# music player in android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

i plan to do a music player which user can choose a song from the list. The song will be played according to what user choose. For now, i already succeed if it only play one song which we can clearly put the url in the code:

```
var myMedia = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/face.mp3', mediaSuccess, mediaError);
```

This is my whole js file:

```
$("#mediapage").live("pagecreate", function(event) {
var page = this;
var mediaStatus;

mediaSuccess = function(){
}

mediaError = function(error) {
    alert('Media Error: '+error.message);
}

var myMedia = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/face.mp3', mediaSuccess, mediaError);

$("#mediaplayLink").live("click",function(e) {
    myMedia.play();
    mediaStatus = setInterval(function() {
        myMedia.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                if(position > -1) $("#status",page).html("Second "+position+" of "+myMedia.getDuration() + " seconds.");

            })
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#mediapauseLink").live("click",function(e) {
    myMedia.pause();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#mediastopLink").live("click",function(e) {
    $("#status", page).html("");
    clearInterval(mediaStatus);
    myMedia.stop();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

and the html code:

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="controlgroup" align="center">
        <a id="mediaplayLink" data-inline="true"><img src='/android_asset/www/images/play.jpg'></a>  
        <a id="mediapauseLink" data-inline="true"><img src='/android_asset/www/images/pause.jpg'></a>  
        <a id="mediastopLink" data-inline="true"><img src='/android_asset/www/images/stop.jpg'></a>   
    </div>    

    <div id="status"></div>
</div>
```

please anyone help??

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code

```
public class Media_player extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        updateSongList();
    }

    private void updateSongList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.song_item, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);
        }
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        currentPosition = position;
        playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
    }

    private void playSong(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(string);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            // Setup listener so next song starts automatically
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    nextSong();
                }

            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void nextSong() {
        if (++currentPosition >= songs.size()) {
            // Last song, just reset currentPosition
            currentPosition = 0;
        } else {
            // Play next song
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

this other class

```
public class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));

    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="No songs found on SD Card." android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/android:empty"></TextView>
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_height="286dp"></ListView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/play" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

song_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: is this code applicable to phonegap? because i develop android for phonegap which i use html5, javascript, css and jquery mobile

Comment: -1: The op is asking for a javascript solution, not a java one